# Is it a good idea to use ObjectSpace to find parent ActiveRecord in a validation chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, nested-forms, objectspace

Considering following models:

```ruby
class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
  validates :parent_id, presence: true
end
```

Goal is to make sure `Child` cannot be created without a parent, i.e. `Father`. Now if father tries to create `Child` in a nested form, by the time the validation `Child` is being validated `Father` has not received an ID yet, thus the validation will fail. One [proposed solution](http://www.rebeccamiller-webster.com/2011/09/validate-polymorphic/) is to use `ObjectSpace` as the following:

```ruby
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true

  validates_presence_of :parent
  validates_presence_of :parent_id, :unless => Proc.new { |p|
    if (new_record? && !parent && parent_type)
      parent = nil
      ObjectSpace.each_object(parent_type.constantize) do |o|
        parent = o if o.children.include?(p) unless parent
      end
    end
    parent
  }
end
```

Is it a good Idea to use `ObjectSpace` (e.g. `Father`) in the validation chain? Can there exist another `Father` in `ObjectSpace` which by chance is being created at the same time and has a child with the exact same attributes as the `Child` in question?